# Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument in a Python method?

Tags: python, oop, methods, self

When defining a method on a class in Python, it looks something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

But in some other languages, such as C#, you have a reference to the object that the method is bound to with the "this" keyword without declaring it as an argument in the method prototype.

Was this an intentional language design decision in Python or are there some implementation details that require the passing of "self" as an argument?

Comment: I bet you would also be interested in knowing why you need to explicitly write `self` to access members - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910020/what-is-the-advantage-of-having-this-self-pointer-mandatory-explicit

Comment: But it looks kinda a boiler plate though

Comment: A bit confusing but worth understanding http://stackoverflow.com/a/31367197/1815624

Comment: http://python-history.blogspot.in/2009/02/adding-support-for-user-defined-classes.html

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I like to quote Peters' Zen of Python.  "Explicit is better than implicit."

In Java and C++, '`this.`' can be deduced, except when you have variable names that make it impossible to deduce.   So you sometimes need it and sometimes don't.

Python elects to make things like this explicit rather than based on a rule.

Additionally, since nothing is implied or assumed, parts of the implementation are exposed.  `self.__class__`, `self.__dict__` and other "internal" structures are available in an obvious way.

Comment: Although it would be nice to have a less cryptic error message when you forget it.

Comment: You can spell it anything (my, this, whatever) and for certain type of class methods, it changes meaning. Not easy to work out your intent and give a "better" message.

Comment: However when you call a method you don't have to pass object variable, doesn't it breaks the rule of explicitness? If to keep this zen, it have to be something like: object.method(object, param1, param2). Looks somehow inconsistent...

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I don't think so, you pass for example two parameters to function, `object.method(param1, param2)`, but get three parameters `def method(self, param1, param2)`. So first parameter passed implicitly, implicitly != explicitly.

Comment: @Vedmant oh, come on. The concept is so simple and easy to understand. I don't even know why I'm getting into this purely academic discussion. Enormous amount of Python code was successfully developed and it works but now someone doesn't find it natural that the first argument of a method will hold a reference to the object on which the method is called. And there's one more reason for `self` to be there. In Python you can't use any symbol which is not available in the current scope (except for assignment) so `self` has to be exactly where it is.

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit" - Isn't the "style" of Python built around things being implicit? e.g. implicit data types, implicit function boundaries ( no { }'s), implicit variable scope... if global variables in modules are available in functions... why shouldn't that same logic/reasoning be applied to classes? Wouldn't the simplified rule just be "anything declared at a higher level is available at a lower level" as determined by indentation?

Comment: Allow me to answer my own comment... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html explains it nicely: a variable declared at the high level in a class is available to ALL instances of that class, so to me that's the reason why we need "self" (or whatever you decide to call it) to distinguish. I'd still argue it could be implemented in a simpler way: why not just have a variable "__self__" (with two underscores either side... i cant get that to display right here) fixed and available with each class to save people putting it in every function?

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" Nonsense detected

Comment: "In Java and C++, `this.` can be deduced"  This is very imprecise wording. The compiler isn't deducing anything. When it sees a variable name, it does a name lookup starting in the innermost scope and going up to the global or class scope.

Comment: let's face it, it just is bad. There is no excuse for this. It's just an ugly relic but it's ok.

Answer (score 73):

It's to minimize the difference between methods and functions. It allows you to easily generate methods in metaclasses, or add methods at runtime to pre-existing classes.

e.g.

```
>>> class C:
...     def foo(self):
...         print("Hi!")
...
>>>
>>> def bar(self):
...     print("Bork bork bork!")
...
>>>
>>> c = C()
>>> C.bar = bar
>>> c.bar()
Bork bork bork!
>>> c.foo()
Hi!
>>>
```

It also (as far as I know) makes the implementation of the python runtime easier.

Comment: +1 for It's to minimize the difference between methods and functions. This should be accepted answer

Comment: This also at the root of guido's much linked explanation.

Comment: This also shows that in Python , when you do c.bar() first it checks instance for attributes , then it checks __class__ attributes . So you can 'attach' a data or function (objects) to a Class anytime and expect to access in its instance (i.e dir(instance) will s how it ) . Not just when you "created" c instance . Its very dynamic .

Comment: I don't really buy it. Even in the cases where you need the parent class, you could still infer it upon execution. And equivalence between instance methods and class functions passed instances is silly; Ruby does just fine without them.

Comment: JavaScript allows you to add methods to an object at run-time, and it doesn't require `self` in the function declaration (mind you, perhaps this is throwing stones from a glass house, since JavaScript has some pretty tricky `this` binding semantics)

Answer (score 59):

I suggest that one should read [Guido van Rossum's blog](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/) on this topic - [Why explicit self has to stay](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

> When a method definition is decorated, we don't know whether to automatically give it a 'self' parameter or not: the decorator could turn the function into a static method (which has no 'self'), or a class method (which has a funny kind of self that refers to a class instead of an instance), or it could do something completely different (it's trivial to write a decorator that implements '@classmethod' or '@staticmethod' in pure Python). There's no way without knowing what the decorator does whether to endow the method being defined with an implicit 'self' argument or not.
>
> I reject hacks like special-casing '@classmethod' and '@staticmethod'.

Answer (score 16):

Python doesn't force you on using "self". You can give it whatever name you want. You just have to remember that the first argument in a method definition header is a reference to the object.

Comment: By convention, it should however be 'self' for instances or 'cls' where types are involved (mmmm metaclasses)

Comment: It forces to put self as first param in every method, just extra text that doesn't make much sense as for me. Other languages work just fine with this.

Comment: am i right ? **always** the first parameter is a reference to the object.

Comment: @MMKY No, for example with `@staticmethod` it is not.

Comment: "You just have to remember that the first argument in a method definition..." I experimented with changing the word "self" to "kwyjibo" and it still worked. So as is often explained, it's not the word "self" that's important but the *position* of whatever occupies that space(?)

Comment: The question is about the mandatory reference to the instance, not to the name used. Any modern language I know is able to relieve the developer form this chore. On the other hand Python is often used without defining any custom class at all ([random example](https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/machine-learning-algorithms-for-beginners-with-python-code-examples-ml-19c6afd60daa)), and methods are just static and global (non OOP), not requiring 'self' or equivalent name, not even a main method. It seems to me *superiority* of mandatory 'self' has yet to be demonstrated.

Answer (score 8):

Also allows you to do this: (in short, invoking `Outer(3).create_inner_class(4)().weird_sum_with_closure_scope(5)` will return 12, but will do so in the craziest of ways.

```
class Outer(object):
    def __init__(self, outer_num):
        self.outer_num = outer_num

    def create_inner_class(outer_self, inner_arg):
        class Inner(object):
            inner_arg = inner_arg
            def weird_sum_with_closure_scope(inner_self, num)
                return num + outer_self.outer_num + inner_arg
        return Inner
```

Of course, this is harder to imagine in languages like Java and C#. By making the self reference explicit, you're free to refer to any object by that self reference. Also, such a way of playing with classes at runtime is harder to do in the more static languages - not that's it's necessarily good or bad. It's just that the explicit self allows all this craziness to exist.

Moreover, imagine this: We'd like to customize the behavior of methods (for profiling, or some crazy black magic). This can lead us to think: what if we had a class `Method` whose behavior we could override or control?

Well here it is:

```
from functools import partial

class MagicMethod(object):
    """Does black magic when called"""
    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        # This binds the <other> class instance to the <innocent_self> parameter
        # of the method MagicMethod.invoke
        return partial(self.invoke, obj)


    def invoke(magic_self, innocent_self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do black magic here
        ...
        print magic_self, innocent_self, args, kwargs

class InnocentClass(object):
    magic_method = MagicMethod()
```

And now: `InnocentClass().magic_method()` will act like expected. The method will be bound with the `innocent_self` parameter to `InnocentClass`, and with the `magic_self` to the MagicMethod instance. Weird huh? It's like having 2 keywords `this1` and `this2` in languages like Java and C#. Magic like this allows frameworks to do stuff that would otherwise be much more verbose.

Again, I don't want to comment on the ethics of this stuff. I just wanted to show things that would be harder to do without an explicit self reference.

Comment: When I consider your first example, I can do the same in Java: the inner class needs to call `OuterClass.this` to get the 'self' from the outer class, but you can still use `this` as a reference to itself; very similar to what you do here in Python. For me it wasn't harder to imagine this. Maybe it depends on one's proficiency in the language in question?

Comment: But can you still refer to any scopes when you're inside a method of an anonymous class, which is defined inside an anonymous class, which is defined inside an anonymous implementation of interface `Something`, which is in turn defined inside yet another anonymous implementation of `Something`? In python you can of course refer to any of the scopes.

Comment: You are right, in Java you can only refer to the outer class by calling its explicit classname and use that to prefix `this`. Implicit references are impossibru in Java.

Comment: I wonder if this would work though: In each scope (each method) have a local variable, that references the `this` result. For instance `Object self1 = this;` (either use Object, or something less generic). Then, if you have access to the variable in the higher scopes, you could have access to `self1`, `self2`, ...`selfn`. I think these should be declared final or something, but it might work.

Answer (score 5):

I think it has to do with PEP 227:

> Names in class scope are not accessible.  Names are resolved in the
>   innermost enclosing function scope.  If a class definition occurs in a
>   chain of nested scopes, the resolution process skips class
>   definitions.  This rule prevents odd interactions between class
>   attributes and local variable access.  If a name binding operation
>   occurs in a class definition, it creates an attribute on the resulting
>   class object.  To access this variable in a method, or in a function
>   nested within a method, an attribute reference must be used, either
>   via self or via the class name.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real reason besides "The Zen of Python" is that Functions are first class citizens in Python.

Which essentially makes them an Object. Now The fundamental issue is if your functions are object as well then, in Object oriented paradigm how would you send messages to Objects when the messages themselves are objects ?

Looks like a chicken egg problem, to reduce this paradox, the only possible way is to either pass a context of execution to methods or detect it. But since python can have nested functions it would be impossible to do so as the context of execution would change for inner functions.

This means the only possible solution is to explicitly pass 'self' (The context of execution).

So i believe it is a implementation problem the Zen came much later.

Comment: Hi I am new to python (from java background) and I didn't quite flow what you said "how would you send messages to Objects when the messages themselves are objects ". Why is that a problem, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Qiulang Aah, in Object oriented programming calling methods on objects is equivalent to dispatching messages to Objects with or without a payload (parameters to your function). Methods internally would be represented as a block of code associated with an class/object and uses the implicit environment available to it through the object it is invoked against. But if your methods are objects they can exist independent of being associated to a class/object which begs the question if you invoke this method which environment would it run against?

Comment: Thus there must be a mechanism to provide an environment, self would mean the current environment at the point of execution but you could also provide another environment.

Answer (score 2):

## As explained in [self in Python, Demystified](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why)

> anything like obj.meth(args) becomes Class.meth(obj, args). The calling process is automatic while the receiving process is not (its explicit). This is the reason the first parameter of a function in class must be the object itself.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x = 0,y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance(self):
        """Find distance from origin"""
        return (self.x**2 + self.y**2) ** 0.5
```

Invocations:

```
>>> p1 = Point(6,8)
>>> p1.distance()
10.0
```

**init**() defines three parameters but we just passed two (6 and 8). Similarly distance() requires one but zero arguments were passed.

Why is Python not complaining about **this argument number mismatch**?

> Generally, when we call a method with some arguments, the corresponding class function is called by placing the method's object before the first argument. So, anything like obj.meth(args) becomes Class.meth(obj, args). **The calling process is automatic while the receiving process is not (its explicit).**
>   **This is the reason the first parameter of a function in class must be the object itself. Writing this parameter as self is merely a convention**. It is not a keyword and has no special meaning in Python. We could use other names (like this) but I strongly suggest you not to. Using names other than self is frowned upon by most developers and degrades the readability of the code ("Readability counts").
>   
> ...
>   In, the first example self.x is an instance attribute whereas x is a local variable. They are not the same and lie in different namespaces.

> ### Self Is Here To Stay
>
> Many have proposed to **make self a keyword in Python, like this in C++ and Java. This would eliminate the redundant use of explicit self from the formal parameter list in methods.** While this idea seems promising, it's not going to happen. At least not in the near future. **The main reason is backward compatibility**. Here is a blog from the creator of Python himself explaining why the explicit self has to stay.

Comment: Great explanation. Finally one that totally made sense. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

The 'self' parameter keeps the current calling object.

```
class class_name:
    class_variable
    def method_name(self,arg):
        self.var=arg 
obj=class_name()
obj.method_name()
```

here, the self argument holds the object obj. Hence, the statement self.var denotes obj.var

Answer (score -5):

There is also another very simple answer: according to the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "explicit is better than implicit".