# When is "self" required?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been using classes for only a short while and when I write a method, I make all variables reference self, e.g. self.foo.

However, I'm looking through the *wxPython in Action* book and notice that "self" isn't used all the time. For example:

```
 import wx
 class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Text Entry Example',
            size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        basicLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Basic Control:")
        basicText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "I've entered some text!",
            size=(175, -1))
        basicText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        pwdLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Password:")
        pwdText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "password", size=(175, -1),
            style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)
        sizer.AddMany([basicLabel, basicText, pwdLabel, pwdText])
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
```

The one below does use "self".

```
import wx
class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Button Example',
            size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Hello", pos=(50, 20))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.button)
        self.button.SetDefault()
    def OnClick(self, event):
        self.button.SetLabel("Clicked")
```

If I remember correctly, "self" is reference to a particular instance of the class, so when is it not necessary? Is there a general rule of thumb?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use `self.attribute` to reference an attribute of your current instance.

You use `wx.Frame.__init__()` to reference a method of the parent class.

You don't use `self` if you only reference a local name (variable) of the method (function) you are in.

These are not "rules of thumb," because there are no exceptions.

---

What is probably confusing you in this particular example is that panel seems to be only a local name in the constructor, so it looks like the panel would disappear, once your constructor returns.

If you look at the documentation to `wx.Panel`, though, you will see that *its* constructor attaches the panel to the parent window, so it will continue to exist, even after the constructor returns.

Magic :)

Answer (score 4):

In those instances, if you do not use `self` then you will create only a local variable of that name. In the first example, `panel` is created as a local variable and then referenced later in the function, but it won't be available outside that function. The act of passing `self` to the wx.Panel constructor associated it with the current object in some fashion, so it doesn't just disappear when the function returns.

Comment: wx.Frame.__init__ references the method of the parent class wx.Frame

Comment: To build on this, I'd say prefer a local variable to an instance variable (i.e. don't use self) unless you really need to keep a reference to the object for later use in the class (e.g. as ButtonFrame.OnClick uses self.button).  Minimising variable scope often makes debugging and maintenance easier.

Answer (score 0):

self is **always** required when referring to the instance itself, except when calling the base class constructor (wx.Frame.__init__). All the other variables that you see in the examples (panel, basicLabel, basicText, ...) are just local variables - not related to the current object at all. These names will be gone when the method returns - everything put into self.foo will survive the end of the method, and be available in the next method (e.g. self.button).

Comment: wx.Frame.__init__ does not reference the instance, so it is not an exception!