# Why is self only a convention and not a real Python keyword?

Tags: python

As far as I know, *self* is just a very powerful convention and it's not really a reserved keyword in Python. Java and C# have *this* as a keyword. I really find it weird that they didn't make a reserved keyword for it in Python. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument into a Python method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method)

Comment: self is not a keyword because in Python self is explicit, unlike C#. So, this is really the same question as the one I linked to in the above comment. Please read it and others linked from it, for full enlightment

Comment: The question is clearly different. Asking why self is nto a keyword deserves a different, and simpler answer, of why an explicit self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guido van Rossum has blogged on why explicit self has to stay: http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

I believe that post provides some insight into the design decisions behind explicit self.

Comment: That's not what was asked. The question is not "why do I need to type self" but "why is self only a convention and not a keyword". It's possible to have `def foo(this):` if you really want to - I believe he's asking why calling it `self` is not forced on you.

Comment: this accepted answer does not actually answer the question

Answer (score 5):

Because `self` is just a parameter to a function, like any other parameter. For example, the following call:

```
a = A()
a.x()
```

essentially gets converted to:

```
a = A()
A.x(a)
```

Not making `self` a reserved word has had the fortunate result as well that for class methods, you can rename the first parameter to something else (normally `cls`). And of course for static methods, the first parameter has no relationship to the instance it is called on e.g.:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        pass

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
b.method()        # self is b
b.class_method()  # cls is B
b.static_method() # no parameter passed
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a method is just a function who's first parameter is used to pass the object. You can write a method like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

def setx(self, x):
    self.x = x

Foo.setx = setx

foo = Foo()
foo.setx(42)
print foo.x    # Prints 42.
```

Whatever the merit or otherwise of this philosophy, it does result in a more unified notion of functions and methods.

Comment: A method is not exactly just "a function": as your example shows, a method can be bound to an object instance, in which case it behaves like a function.  Here, `foo.setx` is a *bound* method, which works like a function, but `Foo.setx` is a *method*, which does not work like a function.  For instance, you cannot do `Foo.setx(instance_from_another_class, 42)`.

Comment: EOL: When we write a emthod, it _is_ a function - and that is what coutns on the answer for this question.  There would be no sense in making "self"  a keyword since for python to be python, users still would have to be able to use any other variable name as the first parameter in a method. As for your concerns, when we make use of methods in a program, they are indeed not functions: they are converted to method objects at attribute retrieval time: http://metapython.blogspot.com/2010/11/python-instance-methods-how-are-they.html

Comment: @EOL: I guess it's a matter of perspective. Try this: `id(Foo.setx.func_code) == id(setx.func_code)`. While the rules about how you can call it may differ between `setx` and `Foo.setx`, they are both implemented as exactly the same function. The only attributes that differ are `__class__` and `__new__`.

Comment: @Marcelo: On the other hand, `id(Foo.setx) != id(setx)`, which shows that the `Foo.setx` *method* is different from the `setx()` *function*, despite the `Foo.setx = setx` assignment.

Comment: @EOL: I don't dispute that. Something would have to be different in order for the same-class restriction to be possible. As I said, it's a matter of perspective.

Comment: @Marcello: Yeah, it's a matter of perspective.  To add to an earlier comment of yours, `Foo.setx` and `setx` also differ in their `__call__` attribute (which, I guess, performs the type check on the first argument).

Comment: @jsbueno: I found the Metaphython blog entry you pointed to very enlightening!  Thank you so much!