# Python TypeError regarding arguments

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
class bla:
    def function1():
        print 1
    def function2():
        bla.function1()

x = bla()

x.function2()
```

I don't understand why I get the error "TypeError: function2() takes no arguments (1 given)" as I don't seem to be passing any argument to `function2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular methods are called with an implicit `self` reference to their object - otherwise they wouldn't be able to access any data members of `x`.

They should always be declared like so:

```
class bla:
    def function1(self):
        print 1
```

if you want them to operate on the object (`self` is loosely equivalent to the `this` pointer in C++, for example).

Alternatively, if you don't care about the object (so you're really just using the class to group some functions together), you can make them `static` like so:

```
class bla:
    @staticmethod
    def function1():
        print 1

    @staticmethod
    def function2():
        bla.function1()
```

In fact, that's the only way you can call `bla.function1()` without an instance of `bla` from your `function2`.

Answer (score 1):

That's cause your calling your function as a method and that automatically binds the method's object as the first argument to your function.

Either do:

```
bla.function2() #a function call
```

or:

```
class bla:
    #normal and correct way to define class methods - first argument is the object on which the method was called
    def function1(self):
        print 1
    def function2(self):
        self.function1()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type:

```
class bla:
    def function1(self):
        print 1
    def function2(self):
        self.function1()
```

`self` (a reference to the object on which the method is called) is passed as the first parameter to each method. The name of this first variable, *"self"* is just a common convention.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the argument `self` to the functions `function1` and `function2`. See the Python [Classes documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html). So your code would be

```
class Bla: # Notice capitalization. 
    def function1(self):
        print 1
    def function2(self):
        bla.function1()

x = Bla()

x.function2()
```

See also the answers to the question [Why do you need explicitly have the “self” argument into a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method).

Basically in Python a call to a member function (like `function1`)

```
x = Bla()
x.function1()
```

is translated into

```
Bla.function(x)
```

`self` is used to refer to the instance of the class `x`.