# Why do we add the self parameter when defining a method in Python

Tags: python, methods, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you need explicitly have the “self” argument into a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method)

Why do I have to add this self parameter

```
    def function(self):
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method - possible duplicate. -1

Answer (score 1):

Because when you define a method inside a class, it automatically creates a descriptor that passes the object instance as the first parameter. If you want to avoid this, use the @staticmethod decorator, or just define your functions outside the class.

As for why the language is designed this way, it wouldn't make sense to do it otherwise in a language without explicit variable creation. If you do a=2, how do you know whether it should be a local or an instance variable? Also, passing it explicitly is just a more elegant design in general.

Answer (score 0):

[Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).