# 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'color'

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

So, my problem is that I'm trying to draw a rectangle but I keep on getting an error saying that `'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'color'`. Can someone help me?

**Full Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    game.new()
  File "main.py", line 23, in new
    self.run()
  File "main.py", line 32, in run
    self.draw()
  File "main.py", line 55, in draw
    self.snake.draw(self.screen)
  File "C:\Users\sidna\Dropbox\Dev Stuff\Games\Snake\sprites.py", line 15, in draw
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'color'
```

**Sprites.py**

```
import pygame


class Snake():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.w = 10
        self.h = 10
        self.velX = 1
        self.velY = 0
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)

    def draw(screen, self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color
                         (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    def animate(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velX
        self.y = self.y + self.velY
```

**Main.py**

```
from settings import *
from sprites import *

import pygame
import random


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize game window, etc

        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    def new(self):
        # start a new game

        self.snake = Snake()
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        # Game Loop

        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.draw()
            self.animate()
            self.update()

    def update(self):
        # Game Loop - Update

        pygame.display.update()

    def events(self):
        # Game Loop - events

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # check for closing window
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        # Game Loop - draw

        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.snake.draw(self.screen)

    def animate(self):
        self.snake.animate()


game = Game()

while game.running:
    game.new()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Python zen **explicit is better than implicit**.

> Often, the first argument of a method is called **self**. This is nothing
>   more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special
>   meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention
>   your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is
>   also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that
>   relies upon such a convention.

Which means you should set the first argument to `self`, and also you forgot a `comma`, code should be like this:

```
def draw(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color,(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
```

Have a look at this question [Why always add self as first argument to class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882317/why-always-add-self-as-first-argument-to-class-methods) and [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to see more details.