# Deduction of "this" in Java?

Tags: java, python, syntax

According to [this highly voted answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68324/1527084) Python made it mandatory to declare `self` in instance methods as the language designer wanted to prevent the deduction of instantiating object like done in Java through `this`.

What is meant by "`this` can be deduced in Java?"

Comment: Why don't you just post a comment to the original answer asking S.Lott what he meant?

Comment: @MattBall Because S.Lott last visited SO two months back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reference an identifier without a qualifier in Java (eg, `something`), the compiler will check whether there is a local variable with that name, and, if not, will deduce that it must be a field.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the original post meant that in some instances Java requires 'this' to be used to make it clear what variable you are referring to.  For instance:

```
public class A {

    private String b;
    private String c;

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b; // <-- this removes confusion for Java
    }

    public void setC(String _c) {
        c = _c; // <-- this is not needed here
    }

}
```