# Python OOP Exercise

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn using classes in Python, and have written this test program.
It is to some extent based on code I found in another question I found here on
Stack OverFlow.

The code looks as follows:

```
class Student(object):
    name = ""
    age = 0
    major = ""

    # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer 
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major
    def list_values():
        print "Name: ", self.name
        print "Age: ", self.age
        print "Major: ", self.major

def make_student(name, age, major):
    student = Student(name, age, major)
    return student

print "A list of students."
Steve = make_student("Steven Schultz",23,"English")
Johnny = make_student("Jonathan Rosenberg",24,"Biology")
Penny = make_student("Penelope Meramveliotakis",21,"Physics")
Steve.list_values()
Johnny.list_values()
Penny.list_values()
```

When I run this, get the error "TypeError: list_values() takes no arguments (1 given)".
In my oppinion I have not given any arguments, but I remove the parenthesis, giving the
code

```
Steve.list_values
Johnny.list_values
Penny.list_values
```

This renders no errors, but does not do anything - nothing gets printed.

My questions:

1. What's the deal with the parenthesis?
2. What's the deal with the print statements?

Answer (score 1):

Python requires you explicitly add the `self` arguments to member functions, you forgot to add `self` to your function decleration:

```
def list_values(self):
```

This defines it as a member function of the `Student` class. see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). When you call the functions as members of the `Student` instances, the `self` variable is added implicitly, thus triggering the exception, since you did not define a function named `list_values` that receives one parameter.

As for removing the parenthesis, this means you are not calling the functions but only referring to the function objects, doing nothing.

Comment: What does that mean? Does it have any practical purpose?

Comment: Assuming you mean the `self` variable - ebarr gave a link to Guido(The guy who started python) covering this. check it out: http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Comment: That was interresting, but actually I meant the other thing, am I just mentioning the name of functions without executing them? It seems terribly strange.

Comment: Functions in python are first-class objects, meaning they can be reffered to by name and passed as parameters to functions/assigned to variables just like any other type. Using the ``( )`` operator is what actually ``calls`` the function (or other ``callable``) referenced by the name.

Comment: It is useful to pass a function object as an argument to another function for example.

Answer (score 1):

The `list_values` method needs to be bound to your Student instance:

You should change:

```
def list_values()
```

to:

```
def list_values(self)
```

For an explanation of why, see:

- [Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument into a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method)
- [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Also this blog post by Guido covers the subject too:

- http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Answer (score 0):

`def list_values():` should be: `def list_values(self):`

In Python, instance methods take `self` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should use `self` in `list_values`.

But you should really define one of the [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) `__str__` or `__repr__` instead. Additionally, you're setting some [class properties](http://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) that aren't necessary.

A simpler implementation would be:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major

    def __str__(self):
        fs = "<name: {}, age: {}, major: {}>"
        return fs.format(self.name, self.age, self.major)
```

Use it like this:

```
In [9]: Steve = Student("Steven Schultz", 23, "English")

In [10]: Johnny = Student("Jonathan Rosenberg", 24, "Biology")

In [11]: Penny = Student("Penelope Meramveliotakis", 21, "Physics")

In [12]: print Steve
<name: Steven Schultz, age: 23, major: English>

In [13]: print Johnny
<name: Jonathan Rosenberg, age: 24, major: Biology>

In [14]: print Penny
<name: Penelope Meramveliotakis, age: 21, major: Physics>
```

Since you're not defining special methods, you might as well use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

```
In [16]: from collections import namedtuple

In [17]: Student = namedtuple('Student', ['name', 'age', 'major'])

In [18]: Steve = Student("Steven Schultz", 23, "English")

In [19]: print Steve
Student(name='Steven Schultz', age=23, major='English')
```

Comment: not nitpicking, but the question was about OOP in python and your answer is about avoiding aspects of classes, or using advance methods such as casting to string.

Comment: @WeaselFox Using `__str__` is not "advanced". It's *pythonic*, as in "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." And OOP is not a be-all and end-all. There are many instances where it is not appropriate. See Jack Diederich's excellent video ["Stop Writing Classes"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

Comment: I agree with what you say, but in the context of the question its not really relevant IMHO. The OP stated he's trying to learn OOP in python, and `__str__` is not the first thing you would start with.