# Pygame Class returning TypeError with not enough positional arguments

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, pygame

I'm starting to learn Pygame and to help draw a rectangle I've made it into a class. This is what's required for the `__init__` part of the `rectangle` class:

```
def __init__(colour, x, y, width, height, thickness):
```

That's 6 arguments. I create a rectangle like this:

```
goalRectangle = rectangle(red, 200, 60, 100, 100, 0)
```

where `red` is equal to `(255, 0, 0)` above, for the purpose of convenience.

However, when I run the program I am told that `__init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given` - but I *am* passing 6 arguments. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `self` parameter in `__init__` .

Try:

```
def __init__(self, colour, x, y, width, height, thickness):
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method) is why you need to explicitly pass a self argument in class constructors in python.

Comment: Oh, of course! I'd added self to a class earlier and it must have slipped my mind when making the `rectangle` class. I'll accept this answer as soon as I can!