# What's wrong with this class method?

Tags: python, class

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def greet(name, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, name)
```

Why doesn't this work? I am trying to access my name in the class and say hi my name is [myname] [yourname]

Comment: What exactly does not work? Provide us a sample usage

Comment: Asking *Why doesn't this work* is not very helpful to the reader. You need to explain what does not work exactly. What you expect should happen, that isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `self` to the method

[Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument into a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method)

so

```
 def greet(self, name, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, name)
```

Comment: This is strange. Why would this be the accepted solution, when `self.name` is defined in the `init` and then passing it as an argument to the  `greet` method. This doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual problem is that you are defining your instance method `greet` as:

```
def greet(name, other_name):
```

Instance methods in Python take the `instance` as first argument in your method definitions. What you are doing here now, is calling that instance `name`. However, in your class's `__init__`, you are using `self` to refer to your instance object. This is where your main problem is coming up.

So, when you actually try to call your method, you are most likely getting something like this:

```
Hi bob, my name is <__main__.Person object at 0x1018ff2b0>
```

So, you are actually printing out your instance object of your `Person` class. Again, you named this `name`. It's like printing out `self`.

There are two things you need to correct here. The first, you need to properly define your instance `greet` method keeping your instance object name consistent.

```
def greet(self, other_name):
```

Then, you need to refer to your instance attributes referring to your instance and accessing the attributes from that object:

So, you want to access `name` in your `greet` method, it has to be as `self.name`.

So:

```
"Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
```

To have a better grasp on all this, you should read more on how classes work in Python. Here is the tutorial section on it:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

use `self.name` instead of `name`:

```
def greet(other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1) You want `greet()` method to be an instance method, then you lack the `self` parameter:

```
def greet(self, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name),
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
adam = Person("Adam")
adam.greet("John")
```

2) You want it to be a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def greet(name, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, name)
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
Person.greet("Adam", "John")
```