# I converted picture to GIF but turtle's bgpic() still not working

Tags: python, image, tkinter, background-image, turtle-graphics

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle as t
import random
bob=Tk()
t.setup(width = 200,height = 200)
t.bgpic(picname="snakesandladders.gif")
def left(event):
    t.begin_fill()
    print("left")
    t.left(90)

def right(event):
    print("right")
    t.right(90)
def forward(event):
    print("forward")
    t.forward(100)


block = Frame(bob, width=300, height=250)
bob.bind("<a>", left)
bob.bind("<d>", right)
bob.bind("<w>", forward)
block.pack()
bob.mainloop()
```

And my error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lolszva/Documents/test game.py", line 6, in <module>
    t.bgpic(picname="snakesandladders.gif")
  File "<string>", line 8, in bgpic
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1481, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "snakesandladders.gif": no such file or directory
```

I am a beginner so I don't really know if I did not import a library. In another, similar question for `bgpic()` not working, it said to convert the picture to gif but for mine it still doesnt work. I'm using Mac OSX Python version 3.8.0.

Comment: Try specifying full path of the file once instead of only file name

Comment: ***"no such file or directory"***: What did you not understand from the `TclError:` message?

Comment: self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: what does this error mean. it happens when i put in the full file name

Comment: @lolszvaz: ***` _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist`***: This means, the image file are found but the image object does not exits in memory. Verify your image with this example: [why-doesnt-a-local-name-with-a-photoimage-object-work-for-a-tkinter-label-imag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797743/why-doesnt-a-local-name-with-a-photoimage-object-work-for-a-tkinter-label-imag)

Answer (score 1):

Although your problem is a missing GIF file, your program will still fail even if the file exists, and is in the correct directory.

The secondary issue is that you invoke turtle standalone atop tkinter.  You can either run turtle *standalone* where it sets up the underlying tkinter root and window, or you can run turtle *embedded* in tkinter where you setup the root and a canvas for turtle to roam.  But invoking turtle standalone atop a tkinter root you created will fail with error:

```
...
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Here's how to implement your program in *standalone* turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def left():
    turtle.left(90)

def right():
    turtle.right(90)

def forward():
    turtle.forward(100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=200, height=200)
screen.bgpic(picname="snakesandladders.gif")

screen.onkey(left, "a")
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.onkey(forward, 'w')

turtle = Turtle()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Put your GIF background image in the same directory as the source code.

You only need *embedded* turtle if you want to add tkinter widgets alongside the turtle canvas.  See the documentation for `RawTurtle` and `TurtleScreen`.

Your window size is small compared to your `forward()` distance -- you may need to adjust one or the other.