# Python3: Can use other than 'self' as a 1st parameter of methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods, naming-conventions

Can this code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def __str__(self):
        return "Point({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)
p=Point(3,5)
print(p)
```

be modified to following code?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(p,x,y):
        p.x=x
        p.y=y
    def __str__(p):
        return "Point({},{})".format(p.x, p.y)
p=Point(3,5)
print(p)
```

It seems to be worked in this case. But it is so naive case. I wonder using other than 'self' will cause some problem in some situations.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument in a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-in-a-python-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument is the reference to the bound variable or object. Its convention to use self but anything else will also work. check the doc [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/).