# Unable to figure out the reason why this code is giving out a type error?

Tags: function, class, printing, arguments, magic-methods

```
class Cards():
    def __init__(self,suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    
    def __str__():
        return self.rank +" of "+ self.suit

card = Cards("Queen", "Diamond)
print(card)
```

TypeError: **str**() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't passed `self` to `__str__` method.

```
class Cards():
    def __init__(self,suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank +" of "+ self.suit

card = Cards("Queen", "Diamond")
print(card)
```

You can read more about this following this thread - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-in-a-python-method)